# terminal server memory usage per user

Tags: service, terminal

I need to run a query against my terminal servers to find the memory usage per user per session. I would like to write a simple batch file that I could run every hour that would print the memory usage per user to a text file. Is there a command similar to QUSER that displays memory usage? I have been searching for a way to do this, but so far have come up with nothing. I'm looking for something that will return information similar to this:

username        00.00mb

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "memory usage" please: virtual address space used? private bytes? Working set? How should shareable bytes be included (especially if shared across sessions)? In virtual memory systems there is no such thing as "memory" even if only looking at a single process, when many processes are involved you need to be very specific.

Comment: I need to know how much RAM is used against the total available RAM for the terminal server. For example, if my server has 16gb RAM, and I have 20 connections, I'd like to know how much memory each user connection is using from the total of 16gb. I don't know how to classify the memory usage. My knowledge of terminal services is really limited, but any way of viewing any memory utilization would be helpful.

Comment: This is nothing to do with terminal services, works the same even before anyone is logged in. Quick version: every process has memory dedicated to it (eg. user data) and things it can share with other processes (eg. dlls). Therefore adding up the total committed memory/page file across all processes (and the kernel) will be more than the total used because shared memory will be multiple counted. There is no single "memory used" value. Perhaps looking at working set (how much physical RAM) is in use across all processes (with an awareness some is shared) is closest to what you want.

Comment: Hi, Richard, the Memory(private working set) across all processes is what I'm looking for.

Comment: By the way there is no *private* working set. Private bytes and working set are two measures of different things.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic stats are available from WMI's [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class (including session id), that should get you started.

To expand on this, here using PowerShell:

1. Use `Win32_Process` to get process details including WorkingSetSize and SessionId.
2. For one process in each session (doesn't matter which) to get the user account you'll need to follow the associations in WMI (a bit like relations in an RDBMS, but WQL – the SQL like language used to query WMI – doesn't do joins).

So something like:

```
$processes = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Proces


# For example pick the first process in session 1
$sessionProcess = $processes | Where-Object { $_.SessionId -ne 0 } | Select-Object -first 1

# Get the session for the process, and then the user account for that session:
$logon = get-wmiobject -Query "associators of{$($sessionProcess.__RELPATH)} where resultclass=Win32_LogonSession"
$user =  get-wmiobject -Query "associators of{$($logon.__RELPATH)} where resultclass=Win32_UserAccount"
```

and `$user` will hold a [`Win32_UserAccount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instance.

NB. I would suggest filtering out session 0 to avoid all the inbuilt parts of Windows being included.